# Why the following cannot be calculate in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am quite new to MATLAB. I am now using r2014a to evaluate a triple integrals:

`fun = @(x,y,z) y.*sin(x)+z.*cos(x)`

The example given on the internet sets all the lower limit and upper limit to be fixed number. I change a little bit: `x` from `0` to `1`, `y` from `0` to `x`, `z` from `0` to `y`. I use the following codes:

`integral3(fun,0,1,0,ymax,0,zmax)`, where I define `zmax` to be `y`, `ymax` to be `x`. But the MATLAB gives error

```
Error using @(y)y...
Error in integral3>@(y)ZMAXXY(x(1)*ones(size(y)),y) (line 141)@(y)ZMAXXY(x(1)*ones(size(y)),y), ...
Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 190)
        top = YMAX(x);`

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 9)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral3/innerintegral (line 137)
        Q1 = integral2Calc( ...

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral3 (line 121)
    Q = integralCalc(@innerintegral,xmin,xmax,integralOptions);
```

Quite interesting, but when I do step by step manually, I can integrate it, what is the problem?

Comment: always post the entire error message please

Comment: Your `x`, `y` and `z` vectors must all be the same size for this to work which from your description it doesn't sound like they are.

Comment: hahah, well, you *did* ask for it @Dan xD

Comment: What do you mean by same size? How to set up the function in order to solve my goal?

Comment: Did you define `zmax` with two inputs: `zmax = @(x,y) y;`?

Comment: it's unclear to me what you're trying to do ... integral3 evaluates the integral in a cuboidal region. Therefore the XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX, ZMIN, ZMAX arguments all need to be scalars. It doesn't make sense to me when you say "I make ymax = x" because x isn't a scalar. Did you mean to say "with the largest possible value from x?" (i.e. `ymax = max(x(:))`  ?). Alternatively, if you're trying to get the integral from a specific hypercurve, then you should be passing in function handles, *not* the matrices themselves.

Comment: @TroyHaskin: I define it as zmax@(y)y only.

Comment: @ Tasos Papastylianou: What I want to do is iterated integration. For example, `int_0^1 int_0^x (x+y) dy dx`. In my case, what I want to compute is `int_0^1 int_0^x  int_0^y fun(x,y,z) dz dy dx`, 0<=y<=x<=1.

Comment: zmax needs to be a function of both x and y. see the example that comes with matlab for `integral3`, it's pretty much spelled out for you :)

Comment: You need to fix that: ["You also can specify zmax to be a function handle (a function of x,y) when integrating over a nonrectangular region."](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral3.html#input_argument_zmin)

Comment: @ Tasos Papastylianou: x,y,z are not matrix. I want to integrate the intervals: 0<=x<=1, 0<=y<=x,0<=y<=z; i.e. 0<=z<=y<=x<=1. What I mean is intervals, but not vector or matrix. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @TroyHaskin: Thanks for your comment. I think I make this mistake.